# How to set lower and upper bound in react react-chartjs-2?

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

The code displays a bar chart of the number of sales of a day from the database in the current week. **The problem I face is that the lower and upper bound is set to the lowest and the highest value of sales per day respectively. Is there a way to make lower bound to 0 and upper bound to max data + 4?**

---

**ReactJs**

```
import React, {useEffect,useState} from 'react'
import {Bar} from 'react-chartjs-2';
import moment from "moment";
import Axios from "axios";


export default function Chart() {
    const [chartvalues,setchartvalues]=useState([])
    var day1,day2,day3,day4,day5,day6,day7,dispday1,dispday7
    const today = moment();
    day1 =moment().day(0).format("dddd").toString();
    day2  = moment().day(1).format("dddd").toString();
    day3  = moment().day(2).format("dddd").toString();
    day4  = moment().day(3).format("dddd").toString();
    day5  = moment().day(4).format("dddd").toString();
    day6  = moment().day(5).format("dddd").toString();
    day7 = moment().day(6).format("dddd").toString();
    
    dispday1 = today.startOf('week').format("DD-MM-YYYY").toString();
    dispday7 = today.endOf('week').format("DD-MM-YYYY").toString();

    var disp1day1 = moment().day(0).format("YYYY-MM-DD").toString();
    var dispday2  = moment().day(1).format("YYYY-MM-DD").toString();
    var dispday3  = moment().day(2).format("YYYY-MM-DD").toString();
    var dispday4  = moment().day(3).format("YYYY-MM-DD").toString();
    var dispday5  = moment().day(4).format("YYYY-MM-DD").toString();
    var dispday6  = moment().day(5).format("YYYY-MM-DD").toString();
    var disp1day7 = moment().day(6).format("YYYY-MM-DD").toString();
    useEffect(() => {
        Axios.post('http://localhost:3001/getdate', {
            day1 : disp1day1,
            day2  : dispday2,
            day3  : dispday3,
            day4  : dispday4,
            day5  : dispday5,
            day6  : dispday6,
            day7 : disp1day7,
        }).then(() => {
           console.log("dates sent!")
           Axios.get('http://localhost:3001/getchartdata').then((response) => {
           setchartvalues(response.data)
           console.log("chartvalues",response.data)

          })
        });
    })
    

    const chartData ={labels: [day1,day2 ,day3 ,day4 ,day5 ,day6 ,day7 ],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "Daily Sales",
            data: 
                chartvalues.map((number)=>{   
                    return number.NoIt
                },)
            ,
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.6)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.6)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.6)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.6)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.6)',
                'rgba(255, 100, 64, 0.6)',
            ]
        }
    ]
    
}
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Sales from {dispday1} to {dispday7} </h1>
             <Bar
                    data={chartData}
                    options={{
                        
                    }}
                />
        </div>
    )
}
```

***Thanks for the help!***

Comment: Please add a [mre]!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the `suggestedMax` property, in the example I setted the stepSize to 1, in case you wont do this it will round it to the next available stepsize to keep the scale scaling in tact.

To start at zero you can set the `beginAtZero` prop in the tick config to true

```js
const data = [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3];
const maxDataEntry = Math.max(...data);

var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data,
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          reverse: false,
          suggestedMax: maxDataEntry + 4,
          stepSize: 1,
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js" integrity="sha512-hZf9Qhp3rlDJBvAKvmiG+goaaKRZA6LKUO35oK6EsM0/kjPK32Yw7URqrq3Q+Nvbbt8Usss+IekL7CRn83dYmw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```